# Execute a file in temp (tempfile)

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python script which creates a temporary file (another python script) in the Temp folder. Then it should proceed to execute this temp file.

I wrote something like this:

```
 with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+b', suffix='.py') as temp:
    stuff stuff stuff
    temp.write(mycode.encode('utf-8'))
    temp.seek(0)
    os.system(temp.name)
```

When I run it, I get the

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

error. I tried to use tempfile.mkstemp instead (hoping that the "close" function would handle this), but nothing changes.

So my question is: How can I create a file, a python script, in the temp folder, execute it, and then delete it?

Thanks for the answers :D

Answer (score 2):

The line `os.system(temp.name)` should be outside of `with` closure.

Doing that however doesn't work here since the file will be removed by then, therefore you need to have the parameter `delete=False` passed to `TemporaryFile()`.

Preferably consider using [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile).

Comment: but outside the with closure the temp file is already deleted

Comment: Outside of the `with` the temporary file will be destroyed.

Comment: Well yeah of course, the `delete=False` must be passed to the function as well.

Comment: @miciodelcheshire The file has to be closed before os.system can run it